# android: Emulator of large resolution showing NullPointerException

Tags: android

I have an application which is working properly in emulator with platform 1.6.But when I run the same on another avd with platform 3.0. It is showing following exception.

```
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.example.app.DirectionsRouteFinder.doProcess(DirectionsRouteFinder.java:189)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.example.util.UrlRun.onPostExecute(UrlRun.java:49)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.example.util.UrlRun.onPostExecute(UrlRun.java:1)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:590)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:149)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:603)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
12-19 10:24:26.372: E/AndroidRuntime(522):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

This the  line of code(Bold) that showing nullPointer Exception .I know that UI should not be changed in doInBackground process of AsyncTask.I am doing those changes in onPostExecute of AsyncTask.And my 3.0 Emulator is very slow.Is this can be a problem??

```
for (RouteVehicle item : Constants.getRouteFinder()) {


                    String alert=item.getAlert();
                    if(!alert.equals("null")){
                    if(alert.equals("max_speed")){
                        maxspeed++;
                        overspeedText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        overlayitem.setMarker(orange);
                            }
                    else if(alert.equals("stoppage")){
                        stopage++;
                        **stoppageText.setTextColor(Color.RED)**;
                        overlayitem.setMarker(red);
                    }
                    else if(alert.equals("geofence")){
                        geofence++;
                        geoText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                             overlayitem.setMarker(red);
                    }
                    else if(alert.equals("tank_empty")){
                        tankEmpty++;
                        tankText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        overlayitem.setMarker(red);
                    }
                    else{
                        sos++;
                        sosText.setTextColor(Color.RED);
                        overlayitem.setMarker(red);
                    }}

                }
```

Please help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check your layout files. you probably referenced an element (see tankText, overlayItem, etc.) that was not in your xhdpi layout.

Comment: I have not created xhdpi layout.. I think it should take normal layout files by default where text views are defined properly.

Comment: layout-v11? i'm pretty sure the problem is in one of your layout folders.

Comment: i get that it's running normally in 1.6. what i'm saying is that there's some other layout folder out there with a different layout description that the one which is loading in your 1.6 emulator. maybe a conflict in layout-hdpi, layout-mdpi, layout-ldpi, etc. there's a detailed explanation of this one in this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers

Comment: is the layout-land act as a layout-port for the tablet?

Comment: yes it does. normal tablet usage is in landscape mode, so your emulator more or less uses layout-land as the default layout. you can prevent or specify this behavior easily, but that's another topic.